# How to create a request scoped bean at runtime with spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring application and want to create a bean at runtime per request to inject it into another class, just like `@Producer` for CDI.

My bean is just a simple POJO:

```
public class UserDetails {

    private String name;

    // getter / setter ... 

    public UserDetails(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My producer class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class UserFactory {

    @Bean
    @Scope("request")
    public UserDetails createUserDetails() {
        // this method should be called on every request
        String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                        .getAuthentication().getPrincipal(); // get some user details, just an example (I am aware of Principal)

        // construct a complex user details object here
        return new UserDetails(name)
    }
}
```

And this is the class where the `UserDetails` instance should be injected:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/something")
public class MyResource {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getSomething(UserDetails userDetails) {
        // the userdetails should be injected here per request, some annotations missing?

        // do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that Spring complains at runtime about no default constructor (of course).

`Failed to instantiate [UserDetails]: No default constructor found`

But this is intended and I want to call my own factory to let it handle the Instantiation.

How can I achieve this? Why is `UserFactory` never called?

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version `4.2.5.RELEASE`

Comment: You aren't injecting a scoped bean... You are just creating a new instance, or spring does that for you. If you want a scoped proxy you need to `@Autowire` it into your controller.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically you aren't using your scoped proxy. You cannot inject a scoped proxy into a method, you have to inject it into your controller.

```
public List<String> getSomething(UserDetails userDetails) { ... }
```

This will lead to spring trying to create a new instance of `UserDetails` through reflection, it will not inject your scoped bean. Hence it complains about the fact you need a default no-args constructor.

Instead what you should do is wire the dependency into your controller instead of the controller method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/something")
public class MyResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getSomething() {
        // the userdetails should be injected here per request, some annotations missing?

        // do something
    }
}
```

The idea is that the `UserDetails` is a scoped proxy and when used will either use the already present object or create a new one based on the `@Bean` method.

Additonally, the `@Scope` annotation in the `UserFactory` has to be modified as follows in order to work:

```
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Comment: As of 4.3 you can use annotation @RequestScope, which includes proxy

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to inject a request scoped bean on a singleton bean.
You need to use a proxy for the `UserDetails`

```
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

Comment: Nope, still the same exception.

Comment: hmm...try setting `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` as you're not using interface for `UserDetails`.

Comment: That works in combination with the answer of @m-deinum

Comment: @M. Deinum's answer is more complete ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need a no arguments constructor in class `UserDetails`.

```
public class UserDetails {

    private String name;

    // getter / setter ... 
    public UserDetails() {
    }

    public UserDetails(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought first, but if I add a no-arg constructor, the bean injected is always `null`. This means the `UserFactory` is still not called.